# ionic - $ionicLoading freezes the whole app, how to change it?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm in the process of making an Ionic Android app. I need to show a loading icon when fetching the data from internet. I use $ionicLoading for this, but $ionicLoading freezes the whole app. Is there a way to show a loading icon, but the app doesn't freeze? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? Do you mean the loading layer prevent you from touch other elements?

Comment: exactly. That's what i mean